# Matter Waves Interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, diffraction, wave-particle-duality

When an EM wave diffracts, I can imagine that its EM field interacts with the charges in a certain obstacle thus inducing a wave behaviour on the charges of the matter that will interact with the EM of the photon.

However, I am having difficulty to make the analogy with matter waves. Since a matter wave is a result of a momentum, which implies kinetic energy, how does a matter wave is created in order to interfere with an electron with, for instance, 200 keV?

Since a single electron can be diffracted, this means that its wave must interfere with other induced matter waves, right? But wouldn't that imply the creation of high kinetic energy particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion comes because you are thinking of probability waves, which is what the interference pattern from elementary particles through the double slit experiment are, as if they are classical waves.

Current day physics accepts that the fundamental framework of nature is quantum mechanical. Classical mechanics, classical electromagnetism are emergent theories from the quantum mechanical foundations, in an analogous way that thermodynamics is an emergent theory on the substratum of statistical mechanics.

The electromagnetic wave is a special case because the classical wave as given by Maxwell's equations emerges from the coherent synergy of a huge number of photons, i.e. elementary particles. If one is theoretically inclined [here is a link](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) which explains how photons build up the electromagnetic wave.

The photon's energy is given as E=h*nu where h is Planck's constant and nu the same frequency that manifests in the emergent from zillions of photons classical wave. The double slit interference appears even for [a single photon at a time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbLzh1Y9POQ), and the pattern gives a probability distribution, the probability of finding the photon at an (x.y) on the screen.

The same is true for [single electron](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJ-0PBRuthc) interference patterns. It is the probability which is given by the square of the quantum mechanical wavefunction that manifests in the pattern. The electrons pass one at a time and are deflected according to that probability. There is no matter or energy wave in the quantum mechanical framework. Just a probability of detection.

Comment: Thank you anna but I'm not sure I understand. If an electron doesn't suffer diffraction, we cannot create a pattern that is a consequence of the probability of detection. What makes the electrons to be deflected in the diffraction process? This sentence was a bit of a surprise to me "There is no matter or energy wave in the quantum mechanical framework. Just a probability of detection." I cannot express the doubts and lack of understanding that this brings to me :)

Comment: Quantum mechanics is a mathematical formulation that fits all the data of the microcosm we know now . It simplest form is the shroedinger equation whose solutions, instead of giving, for example, orbits for the electron around the nucleus, give orbitals. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital . It is the square of the wavefunction that gives a probability of finding the electron in a specific (x,y,z,t). There are no trajectories as in classical orbits for example a satellite around the earth.

Comment: Each electron in the two slit experiment follows the solution of a more complicated quantum mechanical equation that depends on the boundary conditions ( distance of slits etc) and again it will not be a specific trajectory but a probability distribution. It is the boundary conditions that determine the deflection, but the electron is whole when seen on the screen. There are even some experiments that have detected which slit the electron went through without completely destroying the interference pattern:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#With_particle_detectors_at_the_slits

Comment: I should add that the name "wavefunction" comes because the QM equations are wave equations, i.e. have sines and cosines in their solutions. The interpretation of the square of the wavefunction as probability of detection has been tested over and over again and is basic in the description of the microcosm.

Comment: Things are beginning to be a little more clear, but please consider the first half of your second comment: will we change the wavefunction of an electron by putting it into a system? Is the way that the system interferes with the original wavefunction described by an "operator"? Can the electron be described by a similar or completely different wavefunction after moving away from the slit?

Comment: Every measurement, and passing an electron the hurdle of two slits is a measurement, changes the current boundary conditions and potentials entering the QM equations  and thus the specific wavefunction describing what the electron will do next time it interacts/is-detected.

Comment: In first quantization ( which I am using to try and clarify the problem) position, momentum etc are differential operators which operating on the wavefunction will give a corresponding value for the classical request.  The original wave function is derived from the potentials presented to the electron as it advances,  and the boundary conditions. The "original" is the whole package and it has the wave like properties of the amplitude which squared will give the probability of finding the electron's hit on the screen at (x,y). Any change in boundary conditions and potentials changes the WF.